# Amazon SES Strange Email Format

Tags: email, amazon-ses

My email logs are filling up with bounced emails being sent from my domain with a `From` header formatted like so:

`root@support@mydomain.com`

What is causing this?

---

Full log entry:

```
Mar 13 14:05:09 ip-10-122-201-212 postfix/smtp[26788]: 4D21881CA8: to=<root@support@mydomain.com>, relay=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[107.20.142.169]:25, delay=0.12, delays=0.01/0/0.11/0, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[107.20.142.169] said: 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

Comment: Your application is causing the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
```

When sending via SES, you need to set your `From:` header to one of the "verified" email addresses you configured when setting up SES for your AWS account.

You're setting your `From:` address to `root@support@mydomain.com`, which is an invalid email address. You need to set this to a valid email address that you've verifed through the SES console (or API).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue "Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command))".

Following is the work around

1. Check from postfix logs  which "From" address postfix is using.
2. MAP that from address in  "/etc/postfix/generic" like following.

   root@xyz xyz@YourSesDomain.com
3. Run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic`
4. Make sure that you have following in your /etc/postfix/main.cf

   smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
5. Reload postfix service